# Extracting Data from OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, ordereddict, pyrebase

So i have a firebase database

[image: firebase database]

and this is my code to get specific data

```
db = firebase.database()
test = db.child("Users").order_by_child("IDNumber").equal_to(222333123).get().val()

print(test)
```

then the result returns as an OrderedDict

> OrderedDict([('Ays', {'Ays': 'Baby', 'IDNumber': 222333123})])

i want to extract the data and have Ays = Baby and IDNumber = 222333123 as two separate variables. i tried using .items() and putting it into list but i can't seem to separate it. is there any other way?

Comment: `print(test["Ays"]["IDNumber"])` & `print(test["Ays"]["Ays"])` ?

Comment: wait, what if i don't know which child the data is from?

Comment: let's say OrderedDict([('SomeNameThatIDontKnow', {'Ays': 'Baby', 'IDNumber': 222333123})])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be several items in the OrderedDict. It is always safe to iterate the list

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict([('Ays', {'Ays': 'Baby', 'IDNumber': 222333123}), ('Ays1', {
    'Ays1': 'Baby1', 'IDNumber1': 222333123})])

for val in od.values():
    for k, v in val.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
Ays Baby
IDNumber 222333123
Ays1 Baby1
IDNumber1 222333123
```

Comment: got it by adding v which contains the values i need into an array, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.values()` to extract key, value

```
>>> d = OrderedDict([('Ays', {'Ays': 'Baby', 'IDNumber': 222333123})])
>>> list(d.values())
[{'Ays': 'Baby', 'IDNumber': 222333123}]
```

Comment: i did try that one, but how can i extract Baby and 222333123 from the list? sorry but i'm just new to python

Comment: You can iterate over the list to get the value